# SocketTimedOut exception while downloading a file

Tags: android

For downloading a file i am reading from the input stream and writing to the output stream. Things work fine when in Wifi. But in 3G network after few MBs has got downloaded, i am getting the below exception. How can i fix it?

```
-java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:484)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:466)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:374)
at com.mtnplay.app.e.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.mtnplay.app.e.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.mtnplay.app.e.b.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: are you using retrofit?

Comment: No, normal input and output stream to read and write data

Comment: can you post the source code Especially the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change ReadTimeout. try Socket.setSoTimeout() or HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout().

Comment: it is set to 30000

Comment: Both read time out and connection timeout values are set to 30000 ms

Comment: you need to set to 0, it means no timeout, or try 50000)

Comment: Then it will keep on trying if i dont set any timeout

Comment: It is only failing in one country on 3G, rest of the other countries downloading is working fine

Comment: I think in this country too little speed of 3g, try to increase timeout